# How to register postgres to send CIDR data in a proper format

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models, cidr

I am trying to recreate something on an old Django 1.8.19 system.   Figuring out how this used to work is crucial to what I have to do to recreate it in the supported levels of Django.

I have a Django model with a `netfields.CidrAddressField` field which I believe is stored as a CIDR field in Postgress.  But whenever I receive a QuerySet from postgres, I receive a ProgrammingError exception.

I'm assuming that Postgres cannot marshal the data into a format that Python can understand.

Thanks

I believe this is due to a required psycopg2.extras.register that is not installed.  But I believe I've tried all of them.

The definitions are:

```
from django.db import models
import netfields
import ipaddress

class MyCIDR(models.Model):
   net_cidr = netfields.CidrAddressField()
```

The code is:

```
new_cidr = ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'1.2.3.4/24')
MyCIDR.objects.extra(where=['net_cidr = %s'], params=[new_cidr])
```

The error message is:

```
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'IPv4Network'
```

I expected to receive a list of MyCIDRs

```
[ MyCIDR(u'1.2.3.4/24')]
```